# It is possible to get the slug or the last path of a blogger post URL?

Tags: html, xml, blogger, amp-html

There's many codes created by Blogger to call things at the blog

**For example:**

> data:post.url

**That gets the URL of the blog's posts for example:**

> https://www.blog.blogspot.com/2018/07/slug-of-the-url.html

---

### But what about getting the slug or the last path of a blogger's post?

**I have tried with these codes:**

> data:post.urlLastPath
>
> data:post.urlSlug

But without success.

---

### So I think someone here may know how to do this process

**Pick from the Blogger's Post URL for example:**

> https://www.blog.blogspot.com/2018/07/slug-of-the-url.html

**The slug or the last path that looks like this for example:**

> slug-of-the-url

That using only the bloggers codes, HMTL, XML or CSS, because i cant use Java-Script because i’m building an AMP (accelerated mobile pages) ready site.

Comment: Do you mean previous post URL?

Comment: @Bassam example of url: blog.blogspot.com/wow-slug.htm from that i want to get the slug, this: wow-slug, I know how to get that path with JavaScript but I need to do it without it because AMP don’t allow me to do it. So i think I can get it with a short code of blogger. But I need to know how is... data:post.urlSlug don’t works